# How to apply multiple where condition on laravel eloquent having mutliple models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I have a model with four relations like as below

```
 public function custform_formfields()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(FormFieldMapping::class,'field_id','field_id');
    }

    public function custform_fieldtype()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(FieldType::class, 'fieldtype_id', 'html_field_type');
    }

    public function custform_forms()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(CustomForms::class,'form_id', 'form_id');
    }

    public function custform_options()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(FormOptions::class,'option_id', 'option_id');
    }

 $model::with('custform_formfields','custform_fieldtype','custform_forms','custform_options')->whereRelation('custform_formfields',function($q) use ($whereArray) {};
```

But when i search with field name CustomFormsform_name it is giving me error

multi part identifier could not be identifed. Any idea I can search with any parameter including all 4 relationships. Currnetly whereRelation is accepting only function at a time.

Answer (score 0):

to search through relation you need to use whereHas foreach relation take look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 0):

From your Situation I understand that You can achieve the result by defining relation column on which you want to filter. Here Is My Example Code.

```
$query = $model::with(['custform_formfields','custform_fieldtype','custform_forms','custform_options']);

$relationSearchFields = ['custform_fieldtype.name','custform_forms.title']; // array of relation columns to search

$search = $request->search; // search parameter from the request

foreach ($relationSearchFields as $field) {
   $relationSearch = explode('.', $field);
   $query->whereRelation($relationSearch[0], $relationSearch[1], 
   'like', '%'.$search.'%');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `->whereHas()`: [docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

```php
$models = YourModel::whereHas('custform_formfields', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('some_field', 'like', '%some_search_term%');
})->whereHas('custform_fieldtype', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('some_other_field', 'SOME_VALUE');
})->whereHas(...) // whatever other conditions you want here...
->get();
```